# Swipable tabs in phonegap/angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, tabs, swipe

I am working on a Phonegap project using angularJS and bootstrap. I need to create a sliding tabs view very similar to  Android's implementation as in http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html. Of course  the user should be able to swipe left/right to switch between tabs, and there should be animated transition included. Also each tab screen should have its own html and ng-controller. Are you aware of any Angular Directive  providing this functionality? Any idea on how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

ionic framework provide `<ion-sideMenu>` and `<ion-tab>` directive who do the job.

materialize offer Drag Out Menu based on jQuery with a material design style `

```
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
    <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
</nav>
    `
```

http://ionicframework.com/

http://materializecss.com/

Comment: links-only answers are not encouraged since the answer can later be the invalidated if the links change or vanish from the web. Best to copy-paste in the answer the relevant part you meant to show, while attributing proper reference and credit to the author(s).